# Diff between get.put and get.lazyput

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am new to `Getx`'s dependency injection, so can some one explain to me the benefits of `Get.put()` and `Get.lazyPut()` and tell me also what difference they have?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Short answer

- `Get.put()` will put **Immediately**
- `Get.lazyPut()` will put **When you need it**

Answer (score 11):

To my understanding `put` already puts an instance of the class directly in memory while `lazyPut` just puts a builder for it in it.

A benefit of `lazyPut` is that it saves memory until you actually `find` it. And you can also put more complex code in the builder for it. Another benefit of `lazyPut` is that you can also say `fenix: true` on it which means it's able to be reconstructed in case it got disposed of before.

I would think the only benefit of using `put` is that `find` should be slightly faster then when called because it doesn't need to call a builder first to get the instance. I don't know if there are other benefits.

Answer (score 6):

**Get.put() :**

Will inject a dependency and start executing immediately when it's injected, and I mean with that that its lifecycle methods like `onInit()` and `onReady()` will execute when you inject it like this:

```
class ControllerOne extends GetxController {
  int a = 1;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    print('ControllerOne onInit');
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onReady() {
    print('ControllerOne onReady');
    super.onReady();
  }
}


final controller = Get.put(ControllerOne()); // will inject that dependecy, and immediately will call onInit() method  then onReady() method
```

Debug log:

```
 ControllerOne onInit
 ControllerOne onReady
```

**Get.lazyPut() :**

will also inject a dependency, but it will not start executing the lifecycle methods `onInit()` and `onReady()` until you will really use that controller:

```
 class ControllerTwo extends GetxController {
  int b = 2;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    print('ControllerTwo onInit');
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onReady() {
    print('ControllerTwo onReady');
    super.onReady();
  }
}

final controller = Get.lazyPut(() => ControllerTwo()); // will inject that dependecy, and wait until it's used then it will call onInit() method, then onReady() method
```

Debug log:

```
 /* nothing will be printed right now */
```

but if we do use the controller, as an example:

```
controller.b = 10;
```

then the controller will start running will start:

Debug log:

```
 ControllerTwo onInit
 ControllerTwo onReady
```

Hope this clarifies it!

Answer (score 4):

In the case of `lazyPut`, it only creates the instance, and it'll be instantiated only when is used, check more details [here](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/dependency_management.md#getlazyput)